# How to decode JSON event datasets?

Tags: php, json

How would I decode this JSON data to get the Location link of the event? NOTE: When I say Location I don't mean the field "location" in the json data, I am referring to the field which is in "customFields", then has a "value" which is a link to Google Maps, it also has the "type" = 9.

**Problem:** I am currently stuck with a page which looks like the image below, the "Notice: Undefined offset: # in...." error continues for 200 lines, because the JSON file contains the data of 200 events, the JSON included only contains the first event. [image]

**Desired Result:** For the link to google maps page to be echoed on every line. I think the solution is very simple, just changing my Source code (Included) so that it can read the JSON file.

JSON dataset:

```
[{"eventID":152913573,"template":"Brisbane City Council","title":"Clock Tower Tour","description":"The Clock Tour Tower is a &#8216;must-do&#8217; for anyone and everyone in Brisbane!<br /> <br /> For many years, City Hall&#8217;s Clock Tower made the building the tallest in Brisbane, offering visitors a magnificent 360 degree view of the city around them. Whilst the view has changed significantly over the last 90 years, the time-honoured tradition of &#8220;taking a trip up the tower&#8221; happily continues at Museum of Brisbane.<br /> <br /> The Clock Tower Tour includes a ride in one of Brisbane&#8217;s oldest working cage lifts, a look behind Australia&#8217;s largest analogue clock faces and time to explore the observation platform that shares a unique perspective of the city. See if you can catch a glimpse of the bells!<br /> <br /> <strong>Location</strong>: Tour begins from Museum of Brisbane reception on Level 3 of City Hall.","location":"Museum of Brisbane, Brisbane City","webLink":"","startDateTime":"2021-06-13T00:00:00","endDateTime":"2021-06-14T00:00:00","dateTimeFormatted":"Sunday, June 13, 2021","allDay":true,"startTimeZoneOffset":"+1000","endTimeZoneOffset":"+1000","canceled":false,"openSignUp":false,"reservationFull":false,"pastDeadline":false,"requiresPayment":false,"refundsAllowed":false,"waitingListAvailable":false,"signUpUrl":"https://eventactions.com/eareg.aspx?ea=Rsvp&invite=0tva7etjn38te1bve2yj59425pupt7wvscmr1z6depcj9ctnrh7r","repeatingRegistration":0,"repeats":"Every Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday through June 30, 2021","seriesID":152913560,"eventImage":{"url":"https://www.trumba.com/i/DgDhxtvzZEBEz%2AjAEUDofPUE.jpeg","size":{"width":1290,"height":775}},"detailImage":{"url":"https://www.trumba.com/i/DgDhxtvzZEBEz%2AjAEUDofPUE.jpeg","size":{"width":1290,"height":775}},"customFields":[{"fieldID":22503,"label":"Venue","value":"Museum of Brisbane, Brisbane City","type":17},{"fieldID":22505,"label":"Venue address","value":"<a href=\"http://maps.google.com/?q=-27.4693454,153.0216909(Museum+of+Brisbane%2c+Brisbane+City)\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Museum of Brisbane, Brisbane City Hall, 64 Adelaide Street, Brisbane City</a>","type":9},{"fieldID":21859,"label":"Event type","value":"Family events, Free","type":17},{"fieldID":22177,"label":"Cost","value":"Free","type":0},{"fieldID":23562,"label":"Age","value":"Suitable for all ages","type":0},{"fieldID":22732,"label":"Bookings","value":"Book via the <a href=\"https://www.museumofbrisbane.com.au/whats-on/clock-tower-tour/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">Museum of Brisbane website</a>.","type":1},{"fieldID":51540,"label":"Bookings required","value":"Yes","type":3}],"permaLinkUrl":"https://www.brisbane.qld.gov.au/trumba?trumbaEmbed=view%3devent%26eventid%3d152913573","eventActionUrl":"https://eventactions.com/eventactions/brisbane-city-council#/actions/cvuzsak1g2d45mndcjwkp24nfw","categoryCalendar":"Brisbane's calendar|Museum of Brisbane","registrationTransferTargetCount":0,"regAllowChanges":true}]
```

Code so far:

```
 <?php
  $output = file_get_contents("Events.json");
  $decode = json_decode($output, true);

  for($i = 0; $i < count($decode); $i++) {
    if($decode[$i]['customFields'][$i]['type'] == 9){
      echo $decode[$i]['customFields'][$i]['label'][$i]['value'];
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `$i` loop counter twice in the same expression, but the second time you use it it's pointing at non-existent elements. The snippet below 1) treats JSON objects as objects (I find it less confusing when matching code to data), and 2) uses `foreach` to iterate over the arrays.

I've also extracted the latitude and longitude for you into `$latlong`

Try this:

```
$decode = json_decode($json);

foreach ($decode as $event) {
    foreach ($event->customFields as $field) {
        if ($field->type == 9) {
            echo $field->value."\n";
            if (preg_match('/href="(.*?)"/', $field->value, $matches)){
                preg_match('/q=([\-\.0-9]*),([\-\.0-9]*)/',$matches[1], $latlong);
                array_shift($latlong);
                var_dump($latlong);
            }
            
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=-27.4693454,153.0216909(Museum+of+Brisbane%2c+Brisbane+City)" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Museum of Brisbane, Brisbane City Hall, 64 Adelaide Street, Brisbane City</a>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "-27.4693454"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "153.0216909"
}
```

Demo:https://3v4l.org/AkRvI

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is exactly what I need!!!! THANK YOU!!!!